# Is it possible to put html (e.g. bootstrap icon) in DevExpress dxDataGrid column caption?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, devexpress

I have a dxDataGrid and I want to put a Bootstrap icon in the column header 'caption'.

Normal bootstrap html for an icon would be something like:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-gbp"></i>
```

For simplicity, the code for the dxDataGrid is straight from the DevExpress dxDataGrid tutorial:

```
$("#gridContainer").dxDataGrid({
    dataSource: books,
    columns: [
        { dataField: 'author', width: 125 },
        'title',
        { dataField: 'year', width: 60 },
        { dataField: 'genre', visible: false },
        { dataField: 'price', width: 100, format: 'currency', precision: 2 },
        { dataField: 'length', width: 65 },
        { dataField: 'format', width: 90 }
    ],
    columnChooser: { enabled: true },
    allowColumnReordering: true
});
```

So I would like to add the '£' glyphicon to the price column 'caption' field,

```
{dataField: 'price', caption: '<i class=glyphicon glyphicon-gbp></i>', width: 100, format: 'currency', precision: 2 },
```

but the datagrid just displays the html in string format.

Does anyone know how I can input/format the html to get it to render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your web page is using UTF-8 encoding. If so, you do not need to HTML-encode the pound sign. Simply use the actual character in your caption string (without escaping or encoding it):

*Note: I added fake data to the `dataSource` to make it easier to debug as a standalone snippet*

```
<script>
    $("#gridContainer2").dxDataGrid({
        dataSource: [
            {'author':'fred','title':'the book','year':2016,'genre':'sci-fi','price':25.00,'length':'150 pages',format:'hardcover'},
            {'author':'fred','title':'the book','year':2016,'genre':'sci-fi','price':25.00,'length':'150 pages',format:'hardcover'},
            {'author':'fred','title':'the book','year':2016,'genre':'sci-fi','price':25.00,'length':'150 pages',format:'hardcover'}
        ],
        columns: [
            { dataField: 'author', width: 125 },
            'title',
            { dataField: 'year', width: 60 },
            { dataField: 'genre', visible: false },
            { dataField: 'price', caption: 'Price in £', width: 100, format: 'currency', precision: 2 },
            { dataField: 'length', width: 65 },
            { dataField: 'format', width: 90 }
        ],
        columnChooser: { enabled: true },
        allowColumnReordering: true
    });
</script>
```

Notice that the GBP symbol is embedded in the caption as a Unicode character. The benefits of doing this is that it allows the grid to control the size of the character as if it were part of the font. The downside is that the font you choose has to support the character that you are using or you'll get unexpected results.

Example:

[image: I Love Unicode]

[Here](http://unicode-table.com/en/#control-character) is a Unicode character table you can reference. To use any (see above) of these characters in your caption, click on the character in the grid and then click the "copy to clipboard" button. Then, simply paste the character into your string.

#### The jQuery Approach

If this isn't exactly what you're looking for, you can use client-side jQuery to build out your glyphicon and attach it to the cell header when the grid "repaints".

Each of the header cells in the datagrid is the child of ".dx-header-row", so you can easily set a CSS class on them, and work with them using jQuery.

Here is an example that adds a cssClass to the column definition for price:

```
$("#gridContainer2").dxDataGrid({
    dataSource: [
        {'author':'fred','title':'the book','year':2016,'genre':'sci-fi','price':25.00,'length':'150 pages',format:'hardcover'},
        {'author':'fred','title':'the book','year':2016,'genre':'sci-fi','price':25.00,'length':'150 pages',format:'hardcover'},
        {'author':'fred','title':'the book','year':2016,'genre':'sci-fi','price':25.00,'length':'150 pages',format:'hardcover'}
    ],
    columns: [
        { dataField: 'author', width: 125 },
        'title',
        { dataField: 'year', width: 60 },
        { dataField: 'genre', visible: false },
        { dataField: 'price', caption: 'Price in ', cssClass: 'currencySymbol', width: 100, format: 'currency', precision: 2 },
        { dataField: 'length', width: 65 },
        { dataField: 'format', width: 90 }
    ],
    columnChooser: { enabled: true },
    allowColumnReordering: true,
    onContentReady: function () {
        var currencyIcon = $(document.createElement('i')).attr('class', 'glyphicon glyphicon-gbp').text('currencyIcon');

        $('.dx-header-row .currencySymbol').append(currencyIcon);
    }
});
```

By using the `onContentReady` event to append the icon, it will be reattached if the column is moved around. One thing to note is that the `currencySymbol` CSS class will be added to every cell in that column, so be careful when selecting elements with jQuery. If you'd like to append something to ALL `currencySymbol` cells, simply use the following selector:

`$('.currencySymbol')`

I wrote a detailed [blog entry](https://cerkit.com/2016/02/05/dynamically-adding-icons-to-a-boostrap-nav-menu-in-ghost/) that describes this process for use with Font Awesome icons and Bootstrap nav menus, but the concepts are the same.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The first part I'm afraid doesn't help me as the pound sign glyph is just an example (I will be using a variety of icon glyphs that don't appear as characters). The second part is almost there, but is there a way to keep the glyphs from appearing in every column cell? Or did I misread that part?

Comment: Yes, the code above only adds the glyph icon to the header cell. Here is the code: `$('.dx-header-row .currencySymbol').append(currencyIcon);`. To apply the icon to all cells in the column, use `$('.currencySymbol').append(currencyIcon);`. I'm not sure what class the non-header cells use (`.dx-row`, `.dx-content-row`?), but you could use F12 developer tools in the browser to  dive into the grid to find out. Then, if you only wanted to apply the icon to the content cells (and not the header cell), you could use `$('.dx-row .currencySymbol').append(currencyIcon);`.